# AP Calculus BC - Area integration question

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm taking the AP Calculus BC Exam next week and ran into this problem with no idea how to solve it. Unfortunately, the answer key didn't provide explanations, and I'd really, really appreciate it if someone could explain how to solve this problem, and why the answer is (4ln2)/5. It's a non-calculator problem.

> The region is bounded by the curve $$f(x) = \frac{1}{(x+1)(4-x)}$$ and the $x$-axis from $x = 0$ to $x = 3$. What is the area of this region?

I can't seem to get the correct antiderivative of the curve.

Comment: Did you try the partial fraction decomposition method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea here is to use partial fraction decomposition.  We set 
$$\frac{1}{(x + 1)(4 - x)} = \frac{A}{x + 1} + \frac{B}{4 - x}$$
Since 
\begin{align*}
\frac{A}{x + 1} + \frac{B}{4 - x} & = \frac{A(4 - x)}{(x + 1)(4 - x)} + \frac{B(x + 1)}{(x + 1)(4 - x)}\\
& = \frac{4A - Ax + Bx + B}{(x + 1)(4 - x)}\\
& = \frac{(B - A)x + 4A + B}{(x + 1)(4 - x)}
\end{align*}
we obtain 
$$\frac{1}{(x + 1)(4 - x)} = \frac{(B - A)x + 4A + B}{(x + 1)(4 - x)}$$
which is an algebraic identity that holds for every real number except $x = -1$ and $x = 4$.  Since the denominators are the same, we may equate the numerators, which yields
$$(B - A)x + 4A + B = 1$$
which is an algebraic identity that holds for every real number except $x = -1$ and $x = 4$.  In particular, it holds when $x = 0$ and $x = 1$.  Substituting $0$ for $x$ yields 
$$4A + B = 1$$
Substituting $1$ for $x$ yields
$$3A + 2B = 1$$
This gives us the system of equations 
\begin{alignat*}{3}
4A & + & B & = 1\\
3A & + & 2B & = 1
\end{alignat*}
Solving the system of equations yields $A = 1/5$ and $B = 1/5$.  Hence,
$$\int_{0}^{3} \frac{1}{(x + 1)(4 - x)} = \frac{1}{5}\int_{0}^{3} \left(\frac{1}{x + 1} + \frac{1}{4 - x}\right) dx$$
To make the integration easier, factor out $-1$ from the numerator and denominator of $\frac{1}{4 - x}$ in order to obtain
$$\int_{0}^{3} \frac{1}{(x + 1)(4 - x)} = \frac{1}{5}\int_{0}^{3} \left(\frac{1}{x + 1} - \frac{1}{x - 4}\right) dx$$

Comment: When I do the antidifferentiation, I get 1/5 (ln(x+1) - ln(x-4) for 3 and 0. This gives me 1/5 (ln4 - ln-1 - ln1 + ln-1), which leaves me with (ln4)/5 or (2ln2)/5 - which is not the correct answer. Any advice here? :O

Comment: When you integrate, you should obtain \begin{align*} \frac{1}{5}\left(\ln|x + 1| - \ln|x - 4| \right)\bigg|_{0}^{3} & = \frac{1}{5}\left(\ln\left|\frac{x + 1}{x - 4}\right| \right)\bigg|_{0}^{3}\\ & = \frac{1}{5}\left(\ln |-4| - \ln\left|-\frac{1}{4}\right|\right)\\ & = \frac{1}{5}\ln|16|\\ & = \frac{1}{5}\ln 16\\ & = \frac{1}{5}\ln 2^4\\ & = \frac{4}{5}\ln 2\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you so much, you're amazing :]

Answer (score 1):

Take the following hint:

$$\color{red}-\frac1{(x+1)(x-4)}=\color{red}-\frac15\left(\frac1{x-4}-\frac1{x+1}\right)$$

and use the basic properties of indefinite integration (or antiderivation)

Comment: I'm sorry,my algebra is terrible.. I don't how you got the right-hand side of the equation, or why there's a 1/5.

Comment: @Ozymandias I understand, but then you can't seriously expect to tackle this problems by your own, say in an exam, if you can't do the high school algebra...My advice? Practice a lot, perhaps with a tutor, your basic algebra, and anyway try to do common denominator within the parentheses on the right and then you'll see why there is a $\;\frac15\;$ there

Comment: I know - the thing is: it's a week before the exam, I've been self-studying it with no tutors (the reason why I'm coming here for explanations). If I can't figure it out here, then I can only hope something like it won't show up on the exam :/ Which is why a step-by-step explanation would be really amazing for me.

Comment: @Ozymandias Try $\frac{1}{(x+1)(x-4)}=\frac{A}{x-4}+\frac{B}{x+1}\Rightarrow 1=A(x+1)+B(x-4)$. Solve $A$ and $B$ by comparing coefficient.